# Is AWS AMI 'apache' equivalent to Ubuntu 'www-data'?

Tags: ubuntu, users, apache-httpd, chef

I'm trying to convert a Chef script that's used in AWS OpsWorks for an Ubuntu system to a script I can use with my AWS OpsWorks setup for my Amazon Linux AMI installation.

Their Ubuntu Setup:

- `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

My Linux Setup:

- `sudo usermod -a -G www apache`
- `sudo chown -R apache /var/www`
- `sudo chgrp -R www /var/www`

Their chef Script is as follows:

`cookbook_file "/srv/www/wordpress/current/wp-config.php" do
  source "wp-config.php"
  mode '0755'
  action :create
  owner 'deploy'
  group 'www-data'
end`

Do I just need to change their `'www-data'` user to my `'apache'` user to get this script to work with my setup?

Comment: Or you could add the apache user to a www-data group on your server (I think).

Comment: Hi @Caja thanks for the response, say I didn't want to add the ```apache``` user to my ```www-data``` group. Would changing ```'www-data'``` to ```'apache'``` in my Chef configuration work? The reason I ask is because when I run ```groups``` command on my EC2 instance, i only have ```ec2-user wheel www``` groups, there is no ```www-data``` group.

Comment: I would imagine that would work as well, although I have never done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentRoot should be owned by the apache's user or the group who has permission to access DocumentRoot. To check which user or group has permission, you can go to your apache's configuration file and find for user or group. You can find both the entries in configuration file which you can use to give permission to the DocumentRoot. According to that, you can change your chef recipe for user and group.
By default in Ubuntu OS the user and group value is "www-data".